# Do not type newline when enter pressed in textarea in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I need to submit changes when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, rather than typing a newline symbol. I'm using Ember.js and slightly customized TextArea helper.

Here is what I have in my template

```
{{edit-item placeholder="Weight" value=weight insert-newline="acceptChanges" focus-out="acceptChanges"}}
```

in my helper

```
App.EditItemView = Em.TextArea.extend

  didInsertElement: ->
    this.$().focus()
    this.$().blur()

  focusIn: ->
    $this = this.$()
    $this.get(0).select()
    # fix webkit select problems
    mouseUpHandler = ->
        $this.off("mouseup", mouseUpHandler)
        return false
    $this.mouseup(mouseUpHandler)

  attributeBindings: ['style', 'placeholder']

Em.Handlebars.helper 'edit-item', App.EditItemView
```

and in my `acceptChagnges` action

```
# In controller action hook up 
acceptChanges: ->
  $(document.activeElement).blur()
  @get('model').save()
```

The real problem is that when text selected and user types enter key to accept, it also types a newline which replaces all content in textarea, hence the only newline gets accepted.

How to prevent typing new line, but fire an event to accept changes?

Comment: A TextArea is designed to be multiline. If you only want support for a single line why not just use `<input type="text" />` Can we get some context as to why you are trying to do it this way, it's rather unconventional?

Comment: @Scott the problem is that the string can be long and I need to be able to show all content of the TextArea making it higher, that is not possible with TextField. Or possible?

Comment: Is there any way to use [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) in `acceptChanges`?

Answer (score 5):

I had to do this as well recently, and it turns out it's fairly simple. Here is a pretty bare component which does this:

```
App.NoteBoxComponent = Ember.TextArea.extend({

    keyDown: function (event) {
        if (event.which === 13 && ! event.shiftKey) {
            // Don't insert newlines when submitting with enter
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    },

    // This next bit lets you add newlines with shift+enter without submitting
    insertNewline: function (event) {
        if (! event.shiftKey) {
            // Do not trigger the "submit on enter" action if the user presses
            // SHIFT+ENTER, because that should just insert a new line
            this._super(event);
        }
    }

});
```

To use this, just add `{{note-box action='foo'}}` to your handlebars somewhere. The action 'foo' will be triggered when the user hits enter.